# Monitor arm stand that can be parallel to ground/angle adjusted constantly with hands

Tags: monitors, monitor-stand

The [LEVO Deluxe iPad Floor Stand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DYTM9K8) can let you angle the tablet any way you want, put it parallel to the ground so you can lie on your back and look upwards on it. You can turn the tablet you turn your head or elevate your head on a pillow.

I'm looking for something ergonomically the same as the above but which can handle a much larger monitor like a 27 inch all in one computer or a 27 inch touch monitor. A lot of the monitor arms I have googled don't seem to have the ability to be parallel to the floor and constantly/easily rotated slightly/adjusted with your hands.

Long term goal I hope to have a massive screen above me and lie down/adjust its angle without moving much.

So right now, with the Amazon link above, I could accomplish what I'm looking for, for a 12 inch tablet. 27 inch seems like the next goal.